# How to add many to many association in existing models in sequelize node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I want to add many to many association in my node app using sequelize. I am new in sequelize ORM.

I have a eixsting model user.js. I want to create new model project and add want to many to many association

For that I run sequelize create table and migration created
Now in association part what I do that many to many association created

I find multiple these to do that

```
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});
```

But Where I write `User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});` because user model is alreaady existing

Second thing I want to know either `UserProject` automatically created by this or need to manually create it?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to use [`sequelize-cli`](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) and use the `sequelize init` tool, which creates a file which gathers together all your models and creates associations between them. The association is done via class method `associate`, which should be implemented in all of your models (having association to other ones).

This method could look like this (in case of `User` model):

```js
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.Project, { through: 'UserProject' });
    }
}
```

And equivalent in the `Project` model:

```js
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'UserProject' });
    }
}
```

If you do not want to add any other extra fields to the `UserProject` table, it will be created automatically with fields `UserId` and `ProjectId` (if you use the [`sequelize.sync()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#database-synchronization) method - otherwise you have to create the table in migration file). In other case, when you want to add other fields, you would have to create such a model itself.

Comment: I understand you answer but issue is that user model is already created and its migrations are run. How I add this.belongsToMany(models.Project, { through: 'UserProject' }); in user association

Comment: Depends on how your models are created (you can attach this part of code in edit). Anyway, you need to create new migration file for the `UserProject` table to create the relation in database.

Comment: in UserProject no need to give any association?

Comment: In model or in database table? In case of database table, in the migration file, you need to create at least `userId` and `projectId` which are foreign keys to `users` and `projects` tables.

Comment: In model... like we do above in user and project table association

Comment: If you are satisfied with default sequelize foreign keys generation, then, in your `UserProject` model, you do not need to create `userId` and `projectId` fields. They are default by the use of `belongsToMany` method.

Comment: @piotrbienias could you please provide the code of migration file for `UserProject`? is there any primary key in that join table? thanks.